# Flex Project(Maven): Getting Compilation error on Flash Builder 4.7 but compiles successfully on RTC

Tags: maven, flash, apache-flex, flex4.7

My project created in previous version of Flash Builder(FB) and currently I am using FB 4.7, When I change **Flex Server** properties on FB, I face compilation errors.

If I not change my **Flex Server** properties then there is no compilation error(though those properties are pointing to wrong location).

Flex Properties must not be change?

Error:

```
[ERROR]     C:\CMSLite\test2\RTCMLite\src\valueObjects\_DepartmentEntityMetadata.as:[170,30] Method marked override must override another method. override public function getPropertyType(propertyName:String):String
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] CMSLite ........................................... FAILURE [16.422s]
```

Comment: " it compiles correctly but not in the case of Flash Builder" not really helpful to understand the problem, give more details or fb error message

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: add a screenshot or error messages

Comment: @JileniBouguima: Have a check.

Comment: the function getPropertyType marked override doesn't override any other function, just remove override

Comment: Now the build is successful(but this is a generated class and is not intended for modification). Why I get these errors?